# Is there problem with low epoch, high accuracy?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, overfitting

I am training a complex `neural network` model and it starts to overfit epoch 3-4 so I stopped training at that level. So I don't think that there is any wrong thing because my model is not overfitting (I check train/val scores and also use `earlystopping`).

My model works well in the test set so it is also nice thing for me. However, I wonder how should I interpret the low epoch size? Yes, it shows that my model is too `complex` for my problem and fastly `overfitting` but it also increases the accuracy. So if I stop training in the third epoch everything is fine (not overfit, increase the model `accuracy`).

My question is: Am I missing any part of this training process or do you think that there is any wrong thing in my train procedure?